# Importing text file organised in blocks of fixed width data

Tags: python, numpy, text, fixed-width

I have a text file organised in blocks. Each block starts with two lines with the definition of the block (CMBLOCK,component_name,type,n_of_items) and a sequence of data (of variable size) organised as fixed-width format separated by spaces. Here is an example:

```
CMBLOCK,COMP1,ELEM,31
(8i10)
     68085     68088     68099     68101     68103     68104     68105     68106
     68107     68109     68110     68111     68114     68115     68122     68124
     68126     68127     68128     68129     68130     68131     68132     68133
     88553     88554     88556     88558     88559     88563     88564
CMBLOCK,COMP2,NODE,24
(8i10)
      1691      1693      1695      1697      1699      1701      1703      1705
     87776     87777     87778     87779     87780     75350     75351     75352
     75353     75354     75355     75356     75357     75358     75359     75360
```

The items are not necessarily a multiple of the number of columns (e.g. first block).

In Python I have tried different solutions but with no success:

- reading line by line (`cdb_file.readline()`) and then splitting and appending to an array. The problem is that I have not found a way of splitting the string to obtain an array;
- reading the first lines and then the data block with `np.loadtxt` or `np.genfromtxt` (using `skip_header` and `max_rows` for limiting to the current block). Here the functions fail when they reach the last row having less columns. The options `filling_values` and `loose` do not seem to help.

Which way would you recommend using?
Thank you in advance for your suggestions!

P.S. In Matlab I would have used fscanf.

Comment: I seem to have found a way with `np.fromstring(file.readline(), dtype=int, sep=' ')`. But you probably have some smarter ways of doing it.

Comment: Splitting a string produces a list of strings.  You can make an array from that (even an `int` dtype if the strings are compatible).  But if those lines represent a 1d array, `fromstring` is better.  `genfromtxt` is meant for proper 2d csv data.